# Always Encrypted 'where' on multiple values

Tags: always-encrypted

I understand why SQL won't allow this, I want to know if there is some way around this that will allow me to do a where on an encrypted column with multiple values?

I have tried to use a TVP, but SQL does not allow me to join on an encrypted column:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetUsers
    @Users [dbo].[Users_Type] readonly
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[Users] u1
    JOIN    @Users u2
    ON      u1.[Username] = u2.[Users]
END
GO
```

I've tried creating the TVP with an encrypted column, but SQL won't allow me to do so:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Users_Type] AS TABLE(
    [Users] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK_Auto1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NOT NULL
)
GO
```

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'ENCRYPTED'.

Is there any way to get around this limitation?